# How to include grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll with Fody/Costura?

Tags: c#, grpc, fody, fody-costura

Looking forward to this article and issue:

1) https://idmedia.no/general/including-sqlite-interop-dll-into-your-c-project/

2) https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/673

Could not resolve an issue. Did anyone have a similar issue?

Costura/Fody can not include **grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll**.
Does it matter because it is runtime .dll?
[image: Ignore this message check internet connection it is just my suffix sentence to almost every error message.]

**Image 1)** Ignore this message check internet connection it is just my suffix sentence.
.

.

.

.

[image: That is .dll that is not included.]

**Image 2)** That is .dll that is not included.
.

.

.

.

[image: And those are dlls in solution project like on link 1) Set to EmbededResource but still not working.]

**Image 3)** And those are dlls in solution project like on link **1)** Set to EmbededResource but still not working.
.

.

.

.

And this is my FodyWeavers.xml

```
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <Costura IgnoreSatelliteAssemblies='true'
           Unmanaged32Assemblies='grpc_csharp_ext'
           Unmanaged64Assemblies='grpc_csharp_ext'>
  </Costura>
</Weavers>
```

Comment: Did you tried to decompile final dll to see if dll is actually missing? Seems like linkage error.

Comment: Yes I decompiled, but another dll **Grpc.Core.dll** in my project needs that specific dll, and yes after decompile there is no grpc_csharp_ext.dll in final .exe. Any more suggestions. I already tried to add **grpc_csharp_ext.dll** as a reference to a project but I gives me error: Could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building my .NET app which used gRPC. I found out that if I didn't include the global.json file in the root of the repository and explicitly stated the SDK version which I want to use, the build would just use the default SDK version which, for some reason, didn't include the grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll in the output folder.

I would suggest to include the file in your solution and then try to build it.

Example global.json file:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.207"
  }
}
```

If you don't want this file, you can also create a powershell script which creates the file, builds (or publishes) the solution and then removes the file:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.207
try
{
    dotnet build ... (or dotnet publish ...)
}
finally
{
    Remove-Item .\global.json
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used ClickOnce with installer approach, instead of Costura/Fody, but if I will ever use Costura/Fody I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - Grpc.Core is internally searching for grpc_csharp_ext dlls in the App folder:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/e5562a66a4e6bd1900bc9b144587d6d593720c1d/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/NativeExtension.cs#L91

The workaround to put it into the Costura package is described in:

https://www.giters.com/Fody/Costura/issues/641

The main idea is to extract these dlls from the Costura package on app start.